# Removing Windows Partition after hdd clone and boot ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-7

I have cloned to a new SSD an ubuntu/Windows 7 setup which used Windows Boot manager to dual boot. After the cloning i removed the old partitions and formatted the old hd. Now the Windows Boot manager returns a `"boot selection failed because a required device is inaccessible"` which sounds pretty logic to me as i have ruined the prior setup.

I do not have a windows cd in my hands to try to rescue the boot manager. Is there any other way to restore dual boot? If not, i don't really need the windows system, i would gladly sacrifice it to keep the Ubuntu system. How am i going to do that? i am thinking ,delete the windows partition with gparted live disc, but then i have no idea how to fix the grub loader.

Comment: Hope you are not running 14.04 as it is EoL. End of Life. Boot-Repair only works on current versions. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/